# css treat image as part of a word when wrapping text

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width conatiner and a h3 tag inside it. When the text in the h3 tag would overflow my container it wraps into an other line while keeping words together as default. I want to embed an inline image which is connected to the word before it, so when the wrap occurs it is treated as a part of that word.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J239.png) As seen in the example the sun icon breaks into a new line, while i want it to be treated as it is the part of the word 'need', so the page would break the 'need' word into a new line with the sun icon.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hL7La9j/)

Comment: just increase the `width`of the `.holder` div.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind modifying your html, you can wrap the word and them image in an element (div, span, whatever) with `display: inline block`. I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hL7La9j/2/).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the text grouped with the image is longer than one line, such as in the case of a link with a favicon attached to it: https://jsfiddle.net/bmcqve4p/2/

It still does the default behavior of line-wrapping after the image, then starting the next line with the URL and wrapping it at the right edge of the container

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a container with white-space nowrap applied on it.

```css
.holder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
  width: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

span {
  word-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <h3>Example text <span>need<img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/vector-stylish-weather-icons-by-bartosz-kaszubowski/png/256x256/sun.rays.small.png" alt=""></span> more words </h3>
</div>
```